# Исходящие письма от определённого ящика

Tags: postfix, ubuntu

Добрый день!

Есть у меня сервер на Ubuntu 14.04, на котором крутится сайт.
Апач работает от имени пользователя "xxx", и сами сайты находятся в домашней директории этого пользователя.

Стоит postfix, для отправки e-mail с сайта. Соответственно, когда скрипт отправляет письмо, то оно отправляется с адреса "xxx@mysite.ru".

Можно ли настроить postfix так, чтобы все отправляемые пользователем "xxx" письма отправлялись с адреса "yyy@mysite.ru", и как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил, последовательность моих действий такая:

Создал файл:
**/etc/postfix/generic**

В него записал следующее:

```
xxx@mysite.ru yyy@mysite.ru
```

Поправил конфиг в **/etc/postfix/main.cf** 
Дописал следующую строку:

```
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
```

Ввёл команду

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

после чего рестартанул сервер

```
sudo service postfix restart
```

Проверил, теперь письма мне приходят от: **`xxx <yyy@mysite.ru>`**

Думал дальше, как избавиться от этого **xxx**, нашёл следующий способ:

В **/etc/postfix/main.cf** прописываем

```
smtp_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Создаём этот самый файл, header_checks и пишем в него следующее:

```
/^From:(.+@.+).*$/ REPLACE From: yyy@mysite.ru
```

И вводим команду

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
```

после чего опять перезагружаем postfix

В итоге теперь у меня письма приходят не от **`xxx <yyy@mysite.ru>`**, а просто от **`yyy@mysite.ru`**.